# Rhombus and two heights from the obtuse angle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The heights $BM$ and $BN$ are constructed from the vertex $B$ at the obtuse angle of the rhombus $ABCD$. A circle of radius $1$ is inscribed in the quadrilateral $BMDN$. Find the side of the rhombus if $\tan\measuredangle ABD=2$.

[image]

The center $I$ of the inscribed circle in $BMDN$ lies on $BD$ as it's angle bisector of $\measuredangle NDM$.

Let $IP=r=1$. We have $\tan\measuredangle ABD=2$. Let $\measuredangle ABD=\alpha$ so $\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=2\Rightarrow\sin\alpha=2\cos\alpha$ and $4\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1\Rightarrow \cos\alpha=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt5}{5}$. As $\tan\alpha>0, \alpha<90^\circ$ and $\cos\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt5}{5}$. I have tried to somehow use that $\measuredangle ABD=\measuredangle CDB$, but I wasn't able to find anything. How do we continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\angle BDC = \angle ABD, ~\tan \angle BDC = 2$

$\implies DP = \dfrac 1 2$

Also $MP = 1~$ so $~MD = \dfrac 32$

$ \displaystyle BD = \frac{MD}{\cos \angle BDC} = MD \sqrt5 = \frac{3 \sqrt5}{2}$

Finally, $ \displaystyle CD = \frac{BD}{2 \cos \angle BDC}$

Comment: Thank you for the response! How did you get the final equality for $CD$?

Comment: $AC \perp BD$ and it bisects $BD$. So $\frac{BD/2}{CD} = \cos \angle BDC$

Comment: Thank you! But is $I$ actually the middle of $BD$ as @Andrei suggests below?

Comment: No I do not think so. In fact $I$ divides $BD$ in ratio $2:1$